# Tensorflow dataset from generator OutOfRangeError: End of sequence

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generator

Function that returns a generator:

```
def img_x_gen(dir):
    files = glob.glob(f'{dir}/*.jpg')
    for file in files:
        X_i = np.asarray(Image.open(file))
        X_i = X_i / 255.0
        yield X_i, X_i  # It's an autoencoder so return X_i twice
```

Creating the datasets:

```
types = (tf.float32, tf.float32)
shapes = (img_shape, img_shape)
ds_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(img_x_gen, types, shapes,
    args=['train/img_sq']).batch(batch_size)
ds_valid = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(img_x_gen, types, shapes,
    args=['valid/img_sq'],).batch(batch_size)
```

Calling fit method:

```
vae.fit(ds_train, epochs=3, validation_data=ds_valid, verbose=True)
```

I get the error in the question title:

```
OutOfRangeError:  End of sequence
```

The number of examples in the training set is 894, in the validation set it's 247. `batch_size` is 32. I know the model works if I load data into memory.

I've also tried making a generator and manually batching (and passing `steps_per_epoch` and `validation_steps` to the `model.fit` method), but that runs into a similar error: `Your input ran out of data; interrupting training`.

So clearly I don't understand something about generators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly use `model.fit_generator()` with generators instead of `model.fit()`. You are receiving this error because your generator does not yield require number of values as per shape of your input . You can quick fix it by making it an infinite generator.

```
def img_x_gen(dir):
    while True:
        # Make your generator infinite
        files = glob.glob(f'{dir}/*.jpg')
        for file in files:
            X_i = np.asarray(Image.open(file))
            X_i = X_i / 255.0
            yield X_i, X_i
```

and then modify the `fit` function in this way:

```
vae.fit(ds_train, epochs = 3, validation_data = ds_valid, verbose=True, steps_per_epoch = <TRAIN LENGTH>//batch_size,  validation_steps = <VAL LENGTH>//batch_size)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your dataset is iterated to the end, use .repeat() function to repeat your dataset:

```
dataset = dataset.repeat()
```